# How can I Authenticate with custom condition in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

In Laravel documentation there is simple Authentication with condition

```
Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1))
```

In my app User can have one of few statuses. I want to authenticate AGAINST one of those: status != '99'.

Is there a way to achieve this within this request or some extra logic is required before Auth attempt is fired?

Comment: I'm not certain this can be used the way you desire inside `Auth::attempt()`. I handle with custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware), which runs with each request. Might consider this approach, like `Auth::user()->status != 99` then return a `response()` how you want to handle if above is true, otherwise return the default request.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for a `!=` condition with the `Auth::Attempt` method is impossibile, unless you override the `EloquentServiceProvider::retrieveByCredentials` method.

You could check the `User` status during the login process and authenticate only if the the status is different from `99`.

In your check login method:

```php
//check credentials 
if ( ! Auth::validate([ 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password ] ) )
    //credentials are not valid -> redirect

//if credentials are valid, get the user that made last attempt
$user = Auth:getLastAttemped();

//check the status   
if( $user->status != '99' )
{
    //status ok -> log in the user
    Auth::login( $user );

    //redirect wherever you want
}
else
{
    //status is wrong -> redirect to login     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 10 you may provide closure in your array of credentials with Auth::attempt method.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions

````
 
if (Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    fn (Builder $query) => $query->has('activeSubscription'),
])) {
    // Authentication was successful...
}```
````